# pip install not working -- (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: none))

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to download modules to python using pip and it is not working.

python vesion - 3.9.2

pip version - 20.2.3

windows 10 (updated to the most recent patch)

**The error(the same error happened with Flask, scapy and ipython):**

the computer is trying unsuccessfully to reach the package 4 times:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/scapy/`

then this error pops:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scapy (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for scapy

I have tried using pip3, downloading through pycharm, updating python from 3.7.9 to 3.9.2 and I have checked that the path is added to the enviroment variable (`Path=C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;`{....})

What else can I try?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Broken internet connection?

Comment: Internet is working in the browser as usual. I ran pip check and it returned "No broken requirements found" so I assume that internet connection is working. Maybe there is an internet setting I am not aware of

Comment: Perhaps the reason is that you are behind a proxy

Comment: i am not using a proxy

Comment: Are you able to download files via command line with `curl ` or `wget`?

Comment: running ```curl https://www.google.com/``` have given me the desired output(google's html page). I don't know how to futher test this tool, though

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```